# problems with panda dataframe type

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Can anyone help me to understand what I need to do to fix this

The input is a list of domains or IP addresses, so can be strings, numbers, anything really

I've tried to get around the problem by casting as string, but no luck!

Any help would be great

---

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-6c3a37053f0a> in <module>()
     16   for x in index:
     17     #if it ends with a number, it's an IP
---> 18     if str(x[len(str(x)-1)]).isnumeric():
     19       cleandomain.append(str(x[0])+'.'+str(x[1])+'.*.*')
     20     #if its in the CDN list, take a subdomain as well

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'int'
```

Comment: No need to use `len`. You can access the last character with `str(x)[-1].isnumeric()`

Comment: You should include a sample of your dataframe, I'm sure there is a much more efficient way to produce your desired output without a for loop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is in this line

```
len(str(x)-1)
```

Change it to

```
len(str(x))-1
```

In your code you were attempting to subtract 1 from a string, hence the error.